# Ruby regex eliminate new line until . or ? or capital letter

Tags: ruby, regex, newline

I'd like to do the following with my strings:

```
line1= "You have a house\nnext to the corner."
```

Eliminate `\n` if the sentence doesn't finish in new line after dot or question mark or capital letter, so the desired output will be in this case:

```
"You have a house next to the corner.\n"
```

So another example, this time with the question mark:

```
"You like baggy trousers,\ndon't you?
```

should become:

```
"You like baggy trousers, don't you?\n".
```

I've tried:

```
line1.gsub!(/(?<!?|.)"\n"/, " ")
```

`(?<!?|.)` this immediately preceding \n there must NOT be either question mark(?) or a comma

But I get the following syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: (eval):2: target of repeat operator is not specified: /(?<!?|.)"\n"/
```

And for the sentences where in the middle of them there's a capital letter, insert a \n before that capital letter so the sentence:

```
"We were winning The Home Secretary played a important role."
```

Should become:

```
"We were winning\nThe Home Secretary played a important role."
```

Comment: Do you want to use `gsub(/(?<![?.])\n(?!\z)/, ' ')`? Or `gsub(/(?<![?.])\n(?!\s*\p{Lu}|\z)/, ' ')`? Please provide test cases.

Comment: yes @Wiktor Stribiżew only gsub(/(?<![?.])\n/, ' ')  and how can I include [A-Z] inside your [?.] so it includes capital letters too?

Comment: Sorry, I do not think that will work in the long run. Adding `A-Z` is as easy as `/(?<![?.A-Z])\n/`

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining myself enough but we're almost there, the only thing I need to know is how can I add the \n before a capital letter in addition to your gsub method .gsub!(/(?<![?.])\n/, ' '). Example of desired output when capital letters: "We were winning\nThe Home Secretary played a important role."

Comment: Well, I reread your question several times, I feel you want to *move* the newline after `.` or `?`. Try [`gsub(/(?:(?<![?.])\n|\n(?=[A-Z]))([^.?]*[.?])/, ' \1\n')`](https://regex101.com/r/lbwTCu/1)

Comment: No, you understood me well. I got the first two sentences right thanks to your gsub suggestion(your first answer). I edited the question so it appears the third sentence I want modified where there's a capital letter, you can see what I want in my edited question. Sorry for the inconvenients.

Comment: Try a separate [`.sub(/(?<!^) *+(?=[A-Z])/, '\n')`](https://regex101.com/r/8696t9/1).

Comment: Fantastic @Wiktor Stribiżew  can you put both your last and your first sub replies in an answer so I can vote it and give you the tick?

Comment: Ok, added with explanation.

Comment: What do you want returned for "Hello\nWorld\n"? For "He was Dirk, not Dork, according to Sally."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** The answer is not meant to provide a generic way to remove unnecessary newline symbols inside sentences, it is only meant to serve OP purpose to only remove or insert newlines in specific places in a string.

Since you need to replace matches in different scenarios differently, you should consider a 2-step approach.

```
.gsub(/(?<![?.])\n/, ' ')
```

This one will replace all newlines that are not preceded with `?` and `.` (as `(?<![?.])` is a negative lookbehind failing the match if there is a subpattern match before the current location inside the string).

The second step is

```
.sub(/(?<!^) *+(?=[A-Z])/, '\n')
```

or

```
.sub(/(?<!^) *+(?=\p{Lu})/, '\n')
```

It will match 0+ spaces ( `*+`) (possessively, no backtracking into the space pattern) that are not at the beginning of the line (due to the `(?<!^)` negative lookbehind, replace `^` with `\A` to match the start of the whole string), and that is followed with a capital letter (`(?=\p{Lu})` is a positive lookahead that requires a pattern to appear right after the current location to the right).

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there. You need to a) escape both `?` and `.` and b) remove quotation marks around `\n` in the expression:

```
line1= "You have a house\nnext to the corner.\nYes?\nNo."
line1.gsub!(/(?<!\?|\.)\s*\n\s*/, " ")
#⇒ "You have a house next to the corner.\nYes?\nNo."
```

As you want the trailing `\n`, just add it afterwards:

```
line1.gsub! /\Z/, "\n"
#⇒ "You have a house next to the corner.\nYes?\nNo.\n"
```

Comment: ok and I want a new line before capital letter.
    line3= "We were winning The Home Secretary played a
    \nimportant role."
Becomes:
    "We were winning\nThe Home Secretary played a
    important role."

Comment: And I want there were unicorns and pink fairies all around. You have stated the question and I answered it. If you have another one, post another question.

Comment: It's in the title and also in the description: Eliminate \n if the sentence doesn't finish in new line after dot or question mark or capital letter. 
All three

Comment: That was never stated in the description, neither in the effort samples. After all, that contradicts the example given above. I downvoted the question and voted for it to closed due to “unclear what you’re asking.”

Comment: Defoe, you must not change the question after any answers or even comments have been posted, as doing so may render those postings incorrect or nonsensical, as it did here. If you have a follow-on question, post it separately. Moreover, the additional requirement concerning capital letters is vague. Among other things it does not explain what happens when a sentence contains multiple capitalized words. Also, do you really want to convert, "His name is Mudsie" to "His name is\nMudsie"?

Comment: Thanks, @CarySwoveland, I appreciate that. While the main purpose of this resource it to build the searchable knowledge base, many people think that SO was created to make strangers to write code for them.

Comment: I have a different take. If I find a question interesting, other readers may well benefit from answers, so why close the question merely because the asker hasn't demonstrated that he/she made an effort to solve the problem? Wouldn't that amount to [cutting off one's nose to spite their face?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_off_the_nose_to_spite_the_face).

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is to replace all the embedded new-lines with a space, which effectively joins the line segments, then fix the line-end. It's not necessary to worry about the punctuation and it's not necessary to use (or maintain) a regex.

You can do this a lot of ways, but I'd use:

```
sentences = [
  "foo\nbar",
  "foo\n\nbar",
  "foo\nbar\n",
]

sentences.map{ |s| s.gsub("\n", ' ').squeeze(' ').strip + "\n" }
# => ["foo bar\n", "foo bar\n", "foo bar\n"]
```

Here's what's happening inside the `map` block:

```
s                # => "foo\nbar", "foo\n\nbar", "foo\nbar\n"
.gsub("\n", ' ') # => "foo bar", "foo  bar", "foo bar "
.squeeze(' ')    # => "foo bar", "foo bar", "foo bar "
.strip           # => "foo bar", "foo bar", "foo bar"
+ "\n"
```